# Produce one smooth curve on one triangle mesh

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, curve-fitting, smoothing

I hope to get one smooth curve on one triangle mesh. I get one path on the mesh at first. The path consists of vertices of the mesh. I can see the path from the image below.[image]

Each one green dot indicates one vertex on the mesh. The method that I am using is to fit one smooth curve using the vertices and project the smooth curve on the mesh. To project the smooth curve, I find the closest point on the mesh for each vertex of the smooth curve.[image]

However the curve is not on the mesh because it intersects with the mesh. I realize that the vertices need to move along the edge of the triangle shared with the previous vertex.

In my view, there are two kinds of methods to produce the smooth curve. The first kind is to move the points of the curve along the mesh to make the curve smooth. The second kind is to fit the points to obtain one smooth curve and project the smooth curve on the mesh,but the projection should be complex.

Can you give me some advices or links to websites or papers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is really unclear to me what your question is. Is your current method of fitting a smooth curve out of vertices on the path not good enough (because the curve will intersects the mesh)? If you want the curve to lie on the triangle mesh exactly and in the mean time require the curve to be smooth, is it even possible to find such a curve since the triangle mesh is not "smooth" at all?

Comment: I hope the curve is located on the mesh and smooth. To make the curve smooth, the points need to be moved along edges. I find the following paper via the internet and am reading the paper:http://wwwisg.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/visual/files/publications/2014/Lawonn_2014_CAG.pdf

Comment: @fang By reading the paper, I find that curve fitting should be done on manifold not Euclidean space.

Comment: I think the algorithm you describe is correct and the overlap you see is an implementation detail.  Move your points out by some epsilon for example.

Comment: As mentioned by @fang, your curve cannot be smooth if it needs to be inscribed in the surface: there will remain angular points at edge crossings.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are correct. The curve on the mesh is only G1 or C0 continuity. Is only the curve with C2 continuity called smooth curve? Your answer remind me that I need to define the smoothness even if the continuity doesn't change.

Comment: @george I don't understand what you mean that points should be moved out by some epsilon.

Comment: I expressed that the curve will lack G1 continuity (discontinuous tangent direction), just as the surface does (discontinuous normal direction).

Comment: i mean after projecing to the surface, move each point outward a small amount to improve the graphics.

Comment: http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Stefanie.Hahmann/PUBLICATIONS/BH03.pdf To start with